# Custom ROM for RK292X?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom

I'm very newbie.

I have a tablet AOC Breeze MW0712, when I try upgrade the firmware in the official page I see that the chip is RK292X.

[This rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2606861) can be installed in a chip RK292X ?

The steps are the same as when I upgrade the official firmware?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't knot that specific device (never heard of it, to be true). But as a general hint: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: Because my tablet is chinese I can't find a mod oriented by device name, so I'm trying to understand if a ROM is chip oriented or the whole device oriented.